# Azure Functions vs Stored Procedures for Sequential Dependent Calculation Scenario

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-functions, schedule

I have a scenario where I need to read the data from `SQL Server Database (Azure)` and perform `calculations` and save the calculated data back to `SQL Server Database`.

Here, I'm using the `Timer Trigger` Function so that I can schedule one after another as calculations are dependent on each other (a totally of 10 calculations running one after another)

The same can be achieved via `Stored Procedures` in an easy way as they reside in the backend. I want to understand which is the better way to perform/handle such a scenario? in terms of Performance, Scalability, Debugging Capabilities, Cost, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server then definitely SQL Procedure is the right approach because of it's compatibility with SQL Server.

Another recommended approach is use `data flow` activity in Azure Data Factory and transform the data using the available functions. This is easy to use methods as you will get all the required transformation functions in-built.

You can also run Store Procedure in Azure data factory using `Stored Procedure` activity.

Refer: [Create Azure Data Factory data flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-create?tabs=data-factory)